# onRowdatabound not giving label value in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am creating the dynamic grid and adding textbox and label in row dynamically on some button click and bind some data from the database to textbox and label.I want to change the label text color and text box read only for condition depend on database.i have used onRowDataBound event of gridview but not getting any value in the textbox and label for a row. Can anyone helps me to solve this issue? Thanks

```
    protected void grdMasterData_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label status = e.Row.FindControl("lblProduct") as Label;
            if (status.Text == "LY Actuals")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[0].CssClass = "lblProductColor";
                // lbtAction.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I m adding rows dynamically..but its not working

Answer (score 0):

In RowDataBound three row types provided by grid, you are using only DataRow, try to get your values from empty row and footer row because first record will not come in DataRow.